# Google script editor code for pulling multiple video views

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, youtube, screen-scraping

I have a spreadsheet of youtube links that I want to automatically pull view count for on Youtube. I have been able to write code to pull view count for just one youtube ID, but have been having trouble extending this pull to more than 1. See below for the working code. I would have Youtube ID in cell A2.

```
      function getVideoInfo() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var vid = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue()
      var data = YouTube.Videos.list('snippet,statistics', {id:vid});
      var item = data.items[0];
      var info = [item.snippet.title, item.statistics.viewCount];
      sheet.getRange("B2:C2").setValues([info])
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

Of course without data I can't test it.

```
function getVideoInfo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var rgB=sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);
  var vB=rgB.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var data = YouTube.Videos.list('snippet,statistics', {id:vA[i][0]});
    var item = data.items[0];
    var info = [item.snippet.title, item.statistics.viewCount];
    vB[i][0]=info[0];
    vB[i][1]=info[1];
  }
  rgB.setValues(vB)
}
```

I assumed that all of your YouTube code was correct.