# Youtube.Videos.list to retrieve more than 50 records using google script from videoIDs given in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having a spreadsheet which is having more than 1000+ video IDs of youTube in one column. I am trying to retrieve the details of video duration and viewcount and other parameters. However, i am able to get only 50 records not more than that. The error comes up in google script, as soon as i try to get more than 50 records.

The error: "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.list failed with error: The request specifies an invalid filter parameter. getYoutubeVideoStatistics" This is for the line "var statsVideo = YouTube.Videos.list("contentDetails, statistics",{id: videoIDArray, maxResults:50, pageToken: pageToken})

The code i am using is given below is taken from one of the youTube Channel, which have adapted to my needs.

Kindly help, as i am not conversant with the coding.!

```
function getYoutubeVideoStatistics(){

var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var videoIDRange = activeSheet.getRange(4,4,activeSheet.getLastRow()-3)
var videoIDRangeValues = videoIDRange.getValues();
var videoIDArray = videoIDRangeValues.map(function(videoId){return videoId[0];}).join(",");

var pageToken = "";

do {
var statsVideo = YouTube.Videos.list("contentDetails, statistics",{id: videoIDArray, maxResults:50, pageToken: pageToken})
//Logger.log(statsVideo);

  pageToken = statsVideo.nextPageToken;

} while (pageToken);

  var vidDuration = statsVideo.items.map(function(dur){return [dur.contentDetails.duration] })
  var details = statsVideo.items.map(function(stats){return [stats.statistics.viewCount,stats.statistics.commentCount, stats.statistics.likeCount] })

 activeSheet.getRange(4,6,vidDuration.length,vidDuration[0].length).setValues(vidDuration);
 activeSheet.getRange(4,7,details.length,details[0].length).setValues(details);

}
```

Comment: You need the store the recovered id's somewhere outside of the loop otherwise your code will only retrieve the last 50 id's no matter what.   While you may not be conversant in Google Apps Script it is assumed that you are conversant with Javascript.  If not.  Then this may not be the right forum for you.

Comment: Thanks Cooper! this throws an error "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.list failed with error: The request specifies an invalid filter parameter.
getYoutubeVideoStatistics" This is for the line "var statsVideo = YouTube.Videos.list("contentDetails, statistics",{id: videoIDArray, maxResults:50, pageToken: pageToken})

Comment: But i am able to get the required duration and details, if the var videoIDRange contains only 50 videoIDs. Still needs for an improvement in code for more than 50 VideoIDs.

Comment: That might be good to include in the body of the question.

Comment: I have included the error in the body of question.

Comment: Requesting experts to help me out to resolve the challenge being faced in getting the required results from the code mentioned in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for some days and with the help of Cooper  [Thanks Cooper] who has answered this question; [Google script editor code for pulling multiple video views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655885/google-script-editor-code-for-pulling-multiple-video-views), i was able to solve this question. Any user can look for this code.

```
function PostedStackgetYoutubeVideoStatistics(){

var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var videoIDRange = activeSheet.getRange(4,4,activeSheet.getLastRow()-3)
var videoIDRangeValues = videoIDRange.getValues();

videoIDArray = videoIDRangeValues.filter(function(a) {return a.filter(Boolean).length > 0}); // to filter blank values

//    Logger.log(videoIDArray)

var vid_Title = activeSheet.getRange(4,3,activeSheet.getLastRow()-1,1);
var vid_TitleValues = vid_Title.getValues();

var vid_snip_cont_stats = activeSheet.getRange(4,5,activeSheet.getLastRow()-1,5);
var vid_snip_cont_stats_Values = vid_snip_cont_stats.getValues();

  for(var i=0;i<videoIDArray.length;i++) {
    var data = YouTube.Videos.list('contentDetails,snippet,statistics', {id:videoIDArray[i][0]});
    var item = data.items[0];
    var info_1 = [item.snippet.title];
    var info_2 = [new Date(item.snippet.publishedAt),item.contentDetails.duration,item.statistics.viewCount, item.statistics.commentCount, item.statistics.likeCount];
    
    vid_TitleValues[i][0] = info_1[0]; // title
    vid_snip_cont_stats_Values[i][0] = info_2[0]; // published at
    vid_snip_cont_stats_Values[i][1] = info_2[1]; // duration
    vid_snip_cont_stats_Values[i][2] = info_2[2]; // views
    vid_snip_cont_stats_Values[i][3] = info_2[3]; // comments
    vid_snip_cont_stats_Values[i][4] = info_2[4]; // like
  
  }
  vid_Title.setValues(vid_TitleValues);
  vid_snip_cont_stats.setValues(vid_snip_cont_stats_Values);

}
```